# The examples make no sense (translation)

Tags: translation, characters

I have a kid's book for learning "378汉字.“  Each page has six or eight entries, each comprising a photo, the character, and what I suppose is an example of use.  But none of the examples make any sense.  I have looked up the words (according to how a segmenter program divides them) but cannot come up with any reasonable English translation.  I've only tried one page, which has:

```
刀   刀口刀柄
勺   马勺铁勺
筷   筷筒火筷
尺   格尺尺度
叉   交叉叉烧
帘   纱帘帘幕
```

Also tried Google Translate, but (no surprise) the results there were worse than my attempts—and I can't even pass HSK 1 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The punctuation marks are missing

刀 :  刀口; 刀柄 = knife : knife edge; knife handle

勺 :  马勺; 铁勺 = spoon : ladle; iron spoon

筷 :  筷筒; 火筷 = chopsticks : chopsticks canister; stove chopsticks

尺 :  格尺; 尺度 = foot (measurement)/ ruler : ruler; criterion

叉 :  交叉; 叉烧 = fork : cross; BBQ pork

帘 :  纱帘; 帘幕 = curtain : screen; window curtain